# How to change Fedora hostname while being AD-member

Tags: active-directory, fedora, sssd

i#m using a Fedora Workstation in our company Active Directory Domaine. The fedora box is member of the ActiveDirectory (Server 2012 R2).

Now my hardware died and i moved my harddisk to a new hardware. Which is fine with Linux, the Fedora just boots up and everything is fine expect the fact that my Fedora OS now has the wrong hostname which does not match any more with the hardware name ;-)

So, how to change the hostname without messing up my AD-binding?

With a MWindows box i juszt log on as Domaine-Admin and change the hostname in OS and it get's changed in AD as well.

How to do that with a Fedora box?
Can i do the same or do i unbind the Fedora box first, change hostname and bind it to AD again?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 3):

Leave the Active Directory Domain, rename your Fedora and then join back. This way you will make sure the new domain entry will be correct and intact.